# String concatenation in c

Tags: c

I have a variable called  `char *inputstr`, if the string length given to variable is a an odd number, I need to insert a "0" at the beginning of the string variable `inputstr`.

For example:

```
char *inputstr = "1ABc2" .
```

Now I need to append "0" and make it "01ABc2".  How do I achieve this?

```
char a[2] = "0";
char *inputstr = "1ABc2";

if( strlen (inputstr) % 2 == 0)
{
  strcat (a, inputstr);
  strcpy (inputstr, a);
}

if( condition)
{
  Using inputstr variable // here string value is along with         junk characters
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add in a [mcve] to your question so we can see what stage your code is at and be able to give you a more useful answer

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: How are you creating the string in the first place? Please post some code and explain why it doesn't work as you expect it to.

Comment: Since you can not change a string literal, you need another area for the result you want.

Comment: Please don't describe your code, but show it. Also show some examples of strings before and after the "appending". You can [edit] your question.

Comment: I added code in description.. if I use inputstr variable outside the loop . It print junk character along with appended data

Comment: `char a[2]` isn't big enough. You can fit one character with the `NUL` terminator in that string. Arrays do not resize automatically in `c`. If you write "01ABc2" to `a` you will overrun the buffer, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: What is `Char`? that's not a [tag:c] type nor are `Strcat` or `Strcpy` [tag:c] functions, and `Using`? What is that?

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/bCiBaJ)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to set aside a buffer large enough for your target string:

```
/**
 * Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal leads to undefined
 * behavior; to be safe, pointers to literals should be declared "const".
 * You are not going to write the modified string back to what inputstr
 * points to.
 */
const char *inputstr = "1ABc2"; 

/**
 * Compute the size of the target buffer, which is the length of inputstr
 * plus 1 for the leading "0" plus 1 for the string terminator.
 */
size_t targetBufferLength = strlen( inputstr ) + 2; 

/**
 * Allocate the target buffer.  Since targetBufferLength is a run-time
 * value, this will only work with C99 and later.  If you're using C90
 * or earlier, targetBufferLength will have to be a compile-time constant,
 * so you'll have to compute it manually and declare it as
 *
 *    char targetBuffer[7]; // 5 + 1 + 1
 *
 * or
 *
 *    #define TARGETBUFFERLENGTH 7 
 *    ...
 *    char targetBuffer[TARGETBUFFERLENGTH];
 *
 */
char target[targetBufferLength] = {0};
```

Now you can write your new string to the target buffer.  You can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf( target, "%s%s", "0", inputstr );
```

or you can use a combination of `strcpy` and `strcat` (or `strncpy` and `strncat` for the paranoid in the room):

```
strcpy( target, "0" ); 
strcat( target, inputstr );
```

Be aware of the potential for buffer overflow with either method.  Make sure that your target buffer is large enough for the final string.  Using `strcpy` and `strcat` is risky, but using `strncpy` and `strncat` in their place isn't a guarantee of success either.

You could also allocate the buffer dynamically:

```
char *target = calloc( targetBufferLength, sizeof *target );
```

The advantage of this is that you can resize the buffer as necessary if it
isn't big enough:

```
if ( strlen( target ) + strlen( newStr ) > targetBufferLength )
{
  char *tmp = realloc( target, (targetBufferLength + strlen( newStr ) + 1) * sizeof *target );
  if ( tmp )
  {
    target = tmp;
    targetBufferLength += strlen( newStr ) + 1;
    strcat( target, newStr );
  }
  else
  {
    // could not extend target buffer, don't append
  }
}
```

The disadvantage is that you now have memory management issues, and you have to remember to `free` the buffer when you're done with it.

Comment: BTW: I deleted my answer, yours is way better.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: It makes sure the string in `target` is 0-terminated; just in case I forget to initialize the target array.

Comment: Yes but you can use `strcpy()` later. Although there is no need for pointer arithmetic with `strcat()` so I see the point too. I will delete the comment.

Answer (score -1):

you can use memmove as the areas overlap but IMO is better to write a simple routine for it:

`src` - the string to append in front of the `dest`. `dest` has to be big enough to accommodate its new characters

```
char *straddfront(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t srclen = strlen(src);
    size_t destlen = strlen(dest);

    for (int i = 0; i <= destlen; i++)
        *(dest + destlen + srclen - i) = *(dest + destlen - i);
    strncpy(dest, src, srclen);
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Interesting DV. Something wrong or maybe DV are just too cheap

Comment: Not my downvote, but you shouldn't use pointer arithmetic but `[]` notation, and the use of `strncpy` is questionable as with that function you may end up with a non NUL terminated string..

Comment: @Michael Walz not in this case as the `dest` has been already moved `strlen(str)` characters right (including the terminating `0`), and `strncpy` copies only `strlen(str)` of the `src` characters to the **front** of the `dest` string. 'src' is the string to be placed at the front of dest (maybe variable namaes are a bit confusing)

Comment: @Michael Walz `but you shouldn't use pointer arithmetic but [] notation` ??? why not in my functions?

Comment: It's not wrong, but it's less readable and less usual. What is more readable `foo[bar]` or `*(foo + bar)`?

Comment: @Michael Walz this only your opinion - for me pointer notation is same readable as the table one, but I do not need to check if I can for example increment the `foo`.

Comment: `memmove(dst + srclen, dst, dstlen + 1); memmove(dst, src, srclen);` after the two uses of `strlen()` seems more direct than the code shown.  Using `strncpy()` works, but it would be clearer using `memmove()`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I did mention it in my answer. But as I wrote own function will be better in this case. Why? Memmove when the areas overlap moves the memory via the temporary location, which is completely unnecessary in this case and is quite slow as well.

Comment: Only a stupid implementation does that. The standard requires "as if", not "thou shalt"!

Comment: This is so elementary function. Writing takes 3 minutes. Is something wrong with my one? Compiles to the extremely effective code. So I do not know where the problem is. What is better in the memmove version  (except your liking of course, and potentially not educational move of the larger pieces of data, as it may theoretically break strict aliasing rules)

Answer (score -2):

You are searching for `strcat` (or really better `strncat`) defined in `string.h`

But you have to notice:

- `strcat` concatenates two strings, thus you need to use the string `"0"` as the destination
- if destination is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable
- the destination (the first argument of `strcat` i the only one that is modified, not the second argument (that is actually a `const char*`)

Comment: `strcat` adds a string on the end of a string - it doesn't add something to the beginning of it

Comment: Use `"0"` as destination... what's the point of this comment? I'm giving the OP a search direction not the whole solution...

Comment: And one should NEVER recommend `strcat()`. If you explain to someone how strings work in c, they will almost never use `strcat()`. Specially not `strncat()` which is an evil function.

Comment: @The Unholy Programmer writing the Read Only string literal is definitelly the right way for the UB and very likely SEGFAULT as well :)

Comment: @PeterJ_01 fine i admit it,  i don't know c. In the modern world we use the + operator and life is good.

Comment: @The Unholy Programmer `In the modern world we use the +` - so comment the modern world topics

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer And life sucks did you mean? `+` operator is the addition operator, concatenating strings via that operator is not intuitive. Also hiding the details of how strings work, make programs very inefficient. Luckily most programming languages that use `+` as a concatenation operator will optimize the process correctly, but it's still good to understand how can a string be represented internally.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 gotchya

Comment: Guys i'm not writing the software for the OP. I'm giving research direction. But now I'm curious: @iharob-al-asimi what do you use in C that is in standard library?

Comment: You can use `memcpy()` and take care of the lengths and the terminating `'\0'`. Using `strcat()` can be very inefficient, because you would need to compute the length of the resulting string anyway and then use `strcat()` that will again compute the length for each string to append the result at the end, so knowing all the lengths and using `memcpy()` finally terminating the array with `'\0'` is better.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi  in this case `memcpy` will not do.

Comment: Are you aware that `strncat` and `memcpy` implements the SAME algorithm, with the only difference that `strncpy` handles the terminating 0 and treats pointer as char pointer while memcpy as void pointer? http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:strncat and http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:memcpy

Comment: @Matteo Ragni `strncpy` does not handle termination in all circumstances. Learn a bit before you comment

Comment: "Giving research direction" is better suited as a comment - it doesn't make for a good answer

Comment: From the standard library description: The strncat() function appends not more than n characters (a null character and characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by src to the end of the string pointed to by dest. The initial character of src overwrites the null character at the end of dest. `A terminating null character is always appended to the result`. Thus, dest should accomodate strlen(src)+n+1 characters. Source and destination may not overlap.

Comment: @Matteo Ragni do not argue. You initially wrote about strncpy.

Comment: @MatteoRagni: Note that `strncat()` is not the same as `memcpy()`, not even when the first pointer points to the null byte.  All else apart, `strncat()` has to check each byte it copies to see whether it is a null byte; `memcpy()` does not.  But `strncat()` is weird enough in its semantics that the only sane advice is "do not use it".

Comment: Giving advices to avoid the string.h standard library (while keeping a standard programming context) for working with strings is ridiculous. The implementations has been reported in the previous links.

Comment: @MatteoRagni-- nobody said to avoid Standard library string functions; just certain ones. There are plenty of functions in the Standard library that are best avoided, many of them are only retained for the sake of compatibility with legacy code.